# Why can't I see terminal input (stdout) in Linux after executing this Python3 script?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, multithreading, input, stdout

I wrote a Python3 script (shown below, repo here https://gitlab.com/papiris/gcode-motor-stutter-generator)

After I execute it on Linux (Raspberry Pi OS bullseye 32-bit) and either exit by ctrl+c or let it finish; I can't see what I write in that respective terminal tab anymore. The terminal (kde konsole) responds to commands, the text just isn't visible. I can open a new terminal tab and keep working, but the terminal tabs I run this script in never show the text I input again.
Why is this, and how can I fix it?

I tried searching for this topic, but couldn't find anything similar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sys import stdout, stdin 
from curtsies import Input
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

### non-blocking read of stdin
def enqueue_input(stdin, queue):
    try:
        with Input(keynames='curses') as input_generator:
            for _input in iter(input_generator):
                queue.put(_input)

    except keyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)

q=Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_input, args=(stdin, q))
t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
t.start()


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            input_key = q.get(timeout=2)
        except Empty:
            print(f'printing continuously') 
            pass
        
        else:
            if input_key == 'n':
                print('extrusion loop stopped, moving on')
                break
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [mre] help page to find advice on how to reduce the code and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "I apologize for including the whole script, but I don't know what the cause might be." - But you could guess what part of  your code is NOT related to the problem. E.g. random number generation is unlikely responsible for displaying a text. Parsing the input parameters is unlikely a reason too. Eliminate from your code everything which is obviously not a reason of the problem (but make sure that reduced code still reproduces the problem). This is what [mcve] is.

Comment: Apologies, it was a long day. I've narrowed the script down to a minimal reproducible example and edited my question accordingly.
I've also tested the script in the terminal emulator `xvt` and confirmed the same behaviour there.